# How to make xfce (xubuntu-desktop) have no brightness-levels?

Tags: 11.10, xubuntu, brightness

I want to have a smoother experience. With xubuntu-desktop I have just about 6 brightnessteps with my laptop. But in Gnome when the desktop darkens, it happens without steps like in mac. 
Is it possible to do that aways, so the screen goes continously lighter or darker?

Comment: Just as a nitpick, the Mac (and Gnome) have brightness steps. They just have more of them by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adjusting the LCD brightness using the LCD Brightness plugin in the xfce4-Panel. The LCD Brightness plugin is included in [xfce-power-manager](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/applications/xfce4-power-manager).

Or you can look into using [xbacklight](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xbacklight).

Comment: When i type xfce-power-mananger in the console nothing happens. And in the Panel I cant find sth to modify the brightness.

Comment: Also when i type xbacklight -20 or +20 nothing changes.